# Multiple Scala actors servicing one task

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, simd

I need to process multiple data values in parallel ("SIMD"). I can use the `java.util.concurrent` APIs (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`) to process several values in parallels using `Future` instances:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, Callable}

class ExecutorsTest {
  private class Process(value: Int)
      extends Callable[Int] {
    def call(): Int = {
      // Do some time-consuming task
      value
    }
  }

  val executorService = {
    val threads = Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)
  }

  val processes = for (process <- 1 to 1000) yield new Process(process)

  val futures = executorService.invokeAll(processes)

  // Wait for futures
}
```

How do I do the same thing using Actors? I do not believe that I want to "feed" all of the processes to a single actor because the actor will then execute them sequentially.

Do I need to create multiple "processor" actors with a "dispatcher" actor that sends an equal number of processes to each "processor" actor?

Comment: I'm also reading the book "Actors in Scala" and made a toy project using actors: http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/03/mandelactors/

Comment: @Jesper: I am adding your blog to my Instapaper queue to read later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want fire-and-forget processing, why not use Scala futures?

```
import scala.actors.Futures._
def example = {
  val answers = (1 to 4).map(x => future {
    Thread.sleep(x*1000)
    println("Slept for "+x)
    x
  })
  val t0 = System.nanoTime
  awaitAll(1000000,answers: _*)  // Number is timeout in ms
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  printf("%.3f seconds elapsed\n",(t1-t0)*1e-9)
  answers.map(_()).sum
}

scala> example
Slept for 1
Slept for 2
Slept for 3
Slept for 4
4.000 seconds elapsed
res1: Int = 10
```

Basically, all you do is put the code you want inside a `future { }` block, and it will immediately return a future; apply it to get the answer (it will block until done), or use `awaitAll` with a timeout to wait until everyone is done.

---

Update: As of 2.11, the way to do this is with `scala.concurrent.Future`.  A translation of the above code is:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def example = {
  val answers = Future.sequence(
    (1 to 4).map(x => Future {
      Thread.sleep(x*1000)
      println("Slept for "+x)
      x
    })
  )
  val t0 = System.nanoTime
  val completed = Await.result(answers, Duration(1000, SECONDS))
  val t1 = System.nanoTime
  printf("%.3f seconds elapsed\n",(t1-t0)*1e-9)
  completed.sum
}
```

Comment: Nice! I did not know about Scala futures. I am (slowly) reading the beta of "Actors in Scala", but have not gotten to that part. I do not remember "Programming in Scala" (Odersky, et al) or "Programming Scala"  (Wampler and Payne) describing futures.

Comment: How many threads are used in this example? How can configure them? Is there a thread pool in background?

Comment: @michael.kebe - There is a thread pool in the background.  I haven't configured the size of that pool before, so I probably shouldn't comment on customization lest I say something incorrect.

Comment: I am attempting to find the import in your code example in Scala 2.11.7. I cannot find any reference to scala.actors.Futures. Has something changed since you wrote this answer (over 4 years ago)?

Comment: Total Futures newbie here. I am attempting to replicate your code to do an actual fire-and-forget example (i.e. not using the awaitAll call) just to ensure the code in the Futures I create execute even though I never reference them again; i.e. I never call apply.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium - These days Scala uses Akka-derived futures.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Akka, take a look at the ActorPool support: http://doc.akka.io/routing-scala

It lets you specify parameters about how many actors you want running in parallel and then dispatches work to those actors.